# Bash Iteration & Outputting Proper Json

Tags: json, bash, jq

```
function ()
{
    for p in ${param} ; 
        do
            curl -s -g GET '/api/query?param='[${p}] | jq '.'
        done > results.json
}
```

each api query produces

```
  {
    "param": "1",
    "size": "336",
    "area": "600324.0035"
  }
```

have a simple func in a bash script, which i need to generate a json list of all the iterated api query results in json format, for which i can run some other queries with jq, like sorting etc. but this is currently just outputting a bunch of these objects one after the other, without comma separation. silly solutions im trying to solve it within the func are causing other probs, like not sure how to deal with the problem of the final iteration with no comma. whats a better approach here? each result straight into a json array? post processing after the fact? or?

Answer (score 1):

The function body should be s.t. like

```
for p in ${param} ; 
    do
        curl -s -g GET '/api/query?param='[${p}]
    done | jq -s .
```

Comment: ah post does make more sense...

jq -s . is throwing it into an array of arrays

```
[
  [
    {
      "param": "1",
      "size": "0.00305000",
      "area": 250175
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "param": "2",
      "size": "0.00002400",
      "area": 18053
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "param": "3",
      "size": "0.00000050",
      "area": 2801
    }
  ]
]
```

how would i get it to add each object within a single array?

Comment: In the question, you show the output as a simple JSON object. If each output is in fact an array, then instead of the final ., use `add`.